# How to update CloudFront aliase with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I have a `cloudfront` and I need to update the alias (CNAME) of that using the `aws cli`.

According to the documentation I have have a configuration json.

Command I tried looks like this:

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --distribution-config file://cfconfig.json --id <ID>
```

and the `cfconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "CallerReference": "terraformer",
    "Aliases": {
      "Quantity": 1,
      "Items": ["test.dev.domain.com.au"]
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

[image]

I need to only update the `cloudfront` `CNAME` value and how can I simply do that? Why we need the `json` file at all? Are there any other good ways to add only the Cname?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to download current distribution config using `aws cloudfront get-distribution-config` and than amend it according to the changes you need to apply and feed it to `update-distribution` command.